# Select div on page load automatically

Tags: jquery, html

Guys i have 3 divs and when the user select the first one it show some information using JQuery and if the user selected the second div it show another information and so on.

But the problem here is that when the page load it show nothing to the user and wait until the user select any of the 3 divs.

All i want here is to select by default the first div on page load automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this,

```
$(function() {
  $('#id-of-first-div').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the click handler on document ready

```
$(function() {

   // Call the function which executed on first div click

});
```